# VWAP from 1Hr on 1min chart

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

i have added a vwap filter to my buy signal but cant work out how to stop the repainting, my alert is being set on a 1 minute chart but i am requesting the 60minute vwap.  On my chart it shows a change in the vwap on each 1 minute bar, but if i leave the chart loaded it looks like the picture below, but as soon as i reload it updates.
[image]

this is how i have the code setup

```
showPrevVWAP = input.bool(false,  title="Show previous VWAP close" , group = VWAPGroup)

start = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", time)

newSession = ta.change(start) ? 1 : 0



f_vwap() =>
 [hl2, volume ]


[vwapHL2,vwapVOL] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, Time_vwap, f_vwap(),   barmerge.gaps_off,  barmerge.lookahead_on)

vwapsum   := newSession ? vwapHL2*vwapVOL : vwapsum[1]+vwapHL2*vwapVOL
volumesum := newSession ? vwapVOL : volumesum[1]+vwapVOL
v2sum     := newSession ? vwapVOL*vwapHL2*vwapHL2 : v2sum[1]+vwapVOL*vwapHL2*vwapHL2
myvwap     = vwapsum/volumesum
dev        = math.sqrt(math.max(v2sum/volumesum - myvwap*myvwap, 0))
vwap_upper  = myvwap + devUp1 * dev
vwap_lower  = myvwap - devDn1 * dev

prevwap := newSession ? myvwap[1] : prevwap[1]

Long_Vwap_triggers  = Use_Long_vwap   ? Vwap_moving_up  or close<vwap_lower  or (myvwap==vwap_upper and myvwap==vwap_lower and vwap_lower==vwap_upper) : true

if Buy_conditions_met and Long_Vwap_triggers and barstate.isconfirmed 
 alert(........
```

Main problem is that it is causing repainting in the script because i am requesting from 60minute timeframe. Would  the only way to fix b to request from the last hr by turning lookahead off or
Is there a way to get it to update on every bar like it does when i reset the chart.

Thanks for any help